# Trying to add buttons to UIPageViewController, but buttons won't show up even though they're in the view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Here's my code so far:

```
class WarmPushPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let feedViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedViewController")
        setViewControllers([feedViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        let hashtagsButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: self.view.frame.height - 30, width: 70, height: 20))
        hashtagsButton.setTitle("Hashtags", for: .normal)
        hashtagsButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(hashtagsButton)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: hashtagsButton)

        let feedButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height - 30, width: 50, height: 20))
        feedButton.setTitle("Feed", for: .normal)
        feedButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(feedButton)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: feedButton)

        let userButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width-65, y: self.view.frame.height - 30, width: 50, height: 20))
        userButton.setTitle("User", for: .normal)
        userButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(userButton)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: userButton)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension WarmPushPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let _ = viewController as? UserViewController {
            let feedViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedViewController")
            return feedViewController
        } else if let _ = viewController as? FeedViewController {
            let hashtagsViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HashtagsViewController")
            return hashtagsViewController
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let _ = viewController as? HashtagsViewController {
            let feedViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedViewController")
            return feedViewController
        } else if let _ = viewController as? FeedViewController {
            let userViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserViewController")
            return userViewController
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

For some reason, once I get to the margins of the end pages, the labels show up in the margins:

[Hashtag Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTq5a.png)

The labels are also present in my view hierarchy, but my hypothesis is that the problem may lay somewhere here:

[View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22TcX.png)

The end goal is to create my own custom buttons with Sketch assets, where touch up inside on a particular button will segue to the respective page.

Answer (score 3):

1. At the time of viewDidLoad view frame is actual interface builder default frame. So button may reach out of bounds. Try by setting centre frame button will be visible or add the button in viewDidLoad and update the button frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews methods.
2. UIPageViewController contains a gesture recogniser. So adding buttons also no use.
   **Suggested Method to achieve your needs**
   Instead of adding UIButton to UIPageViewController, create a super view-controller(UIViewController) contains subview as UIButtons and UIPageViewController.

Reference Links : https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/11/move-uipageviewcontroller-dots/

[iOS: UIPageViewController - Use button to jump to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835805/ios-uipageviewcontroller-use-button-to-jump-to-next-page)

Comment: Thank you! Will try this and let you know :)